# How to re-trigger (or late-trigger) a `mousedown` event in jQuery?

Tags: events, jquery-plugins, jquery

One question bugs my mind lately: In a `mousedown` handler I use `.preventDefault` on the event to prevent text selection while dragging:

```
$(document).bind('mousedown', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

So far so good.

Then, while still having the mouse button pressed down, I would like to wait for a `longclick` event to be triggered (http://github.com/pisi/Longclick) and have the `longclick` handler to somehow resume the original `mousedown` event and commence the text selection like if the event's default wasn't ever prevented.

**Is there a way to kind of late-trigger an otherwise native mouse event?**

Is `.trigger` capable to somehow accept an existing (stored) event object? For example something like this?:

```
var originalEvent;

$(document)
    .bind('mousedown', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        originalEvent= event;
    })
    .bind('longclick', function(event){
        $(event.target).trigger(originalEvent)
    })
```

I'm after being able to drag an entire text paragraph and still offer the possibility to perform text selection within the paragraph.

All answers, suggestions and thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an event object to `trigger` works as far as jQuery is concerned (event handlers bound with jQuery will be executed, and receive the object as a parameter), which allows you to do cool stuff like [this](http://kernowsoul.com/blog/2010/08/20/programatically-simulating-javascript-events-in-your-test-environment), but no default action will take place. Most browsers support the DOM level 2 specification, [dispatchEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent), except for [the usual suspect](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/DocumentDispatchEventMethod), which has [fireEvent](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvtddtm.php) instead, which is pretty useless as it does not trigger the default action.

Comment: OK, Tgr. Thanks for clarifying. I posted this issue to jQuery Forums too and got the very same answer (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-re-trigger-or-late-trigger-a-mousedown-event-in-jquery#14737000001842174). Seems like this is not possible after all. Bummer.